# bibliography with latex and Arxiv

Tags: bibliographies

Up to now in my master's thesis I used the standard management of the bibliography in latex, the manual one, i.e.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{bardi} 
Bardi, Martino, Annalisa Cesaroni, and Luigi Manca. 
Convergence by viscosity methods in multiscale financial models with stochastic volatility. 
SIAM Journal on Financial Mathematics 1.1 (2010): 230-265.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Now I want to publish an article based on my thesis. The article is ready and I want to publish the preprint on Arxiv.

My question is: can I use the standard bibliography (the one above) or is there some problems with it? I mean if it is manual how will it result on google scholar that I cited the documents that I mention in the bibliography, since no links to the documents are inserted?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure how far this is a TeX question. In fact, you *must* use the standard bibliography with arXiv; they don't run bibtex or biber. arXiv has its own way of counting citations. How/if google scholar does, I do not know, but that is definitely off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: From Q&A from academia.SE (e.g. https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/103508/42707) it looks like google scholar fetches citations from arXiv, albeit with a certain delay.